# Insert the minified javascripts in the returned html page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm wondering if there is a way for me to make MVC5 include all my javascripts in their minified form inside the page that is being returned..

i.e. instead of the browser needing to load an external file such as allmyminifiedbundledjavascripts.js the contents of this is already included in my page in a `<script>` tag

The benafits of this should be:

1. The page loads faster as there are less requests
2. No need to really wait for document load before running scripts..
3. Google is doing it and I want to see if I like it (check the source on google.com).

I can't think of any reasons why this is a horrible idea.. if there are any please enlighten me.

Comment: Multiple requests can run in parallel. I know, you'd say: "it all goes across the same wire (unless JS code is on a different server)", but the browser could be busy rendering the downloaded HTML while it's still downloading the JS, so you save a bit of time and get better responsiveness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tradeoff between caching the file and having it inline. A large file that is cached will load faster on subsequent requests to the same page compared to an inline script tag that has to be downloaded every time.

Html 5 supports async requests on script files so if you have meaningful content to show that doesn't rely on scripting you can specify `async` on your tag.

[Google is using some module for Apache and Nginx](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-js-inline) and demonstrates how they are able to programmatically inline them.

Otherwise here is a small untested piece of code that accomplished what you want...

```
var bundleURL = Scripts.Url("~/bundles/jquery");
var fullUrl = (Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + bundleURL.ToString());
var client = new WebClient();
var minJS = client.DownloadString(fullUrl);

ViewBag.Javascript = minJS;

<script type="text/javascript">
    @ViewBag.Javascript
</script>
```

Yeah, the goal of minimizing requests led to another request. Because of the way bundling works in MVC it's sort of a lost cause. The bundle is a virtual file and doesn't exist until a request is made for it. So you have to mock that behavior to get the right stuff back. Probably a better way (though more tedious) would be to minify independently and then just open and read the file in instead of making a request for it.